# Can't connect to Oracle DB from within my dll

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, dll

I have an external dll (that written in c#) which is responsible of connecting to my DB.
I"m using this dll in my node.js application (Javascript). 
 When connecting to MSS DB connection result is true, when connecting to Oracle db it constantly fails with no option to know what went wrong.

but if im connecting to the Oracle DB thru a test project (written in c#) in my visual studio ,  the result is true.

the problem accord only when i use the dll thru the nodejs.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This are different databases and need different connection modules.

I would suggest writing a separate connection in node as it is really easy with the node-oracledb module:

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');

oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : "hr",
    password      : "welcome",
    connectString : "localhost/XE"
  },
  function(err, connection)
  {
    if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
    connection.execute(
      "SELECT department_id, department_name "
    + "FROM departments "
    + "WHERE department_id < 70 "
    + "ORDER BY department_id",
      function(err, result)
      {
        if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
        console.log(result.rows);
      });
  });
```

You need to install the module first using npm.

More info here: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/introducing_node_oracledb_a_node